How can I use multiple monitors in Unity?
I am trying to work with two monitors; I want to have two cameras in my scene, such that each camera projects to a different monitor. I tried to follow this guide, which says that I have to change the "Target Display" property of the Camera component. However, my Camera component does not have this property - it looks like this:

It has a Target Eye, but not a Target Display. My editor version is 6000.0.24f1.
How can I change the target display of my camera?

I have a project using URP, version 2022.3.47f1, and this is available by default. Seems like a demo issue for me. Maybe trying that same thing on a full release or switching render pipelines might help, but I'm not sure... anyways, good luck!

I'm not able to reproduce this on the current stable version, Unity 6000.0.31f1.
Creating a new project with the "Universal 3D: Core" template, the default Main Camera looks like this, with a "Target Display" field under the "Output" section:

It looks similar to me when using the VR or High Definition templates. Some details vary, but "Output > Target Display" is present in all of these.
If you're not seeing this, consider updating your Unity editor version - maybe it was a bug in the earlier version?

You are right! It was probably a bug in the editor version.
